# Rotating divs with javascript on mouseenter and rotating them back to original position on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to make div rotate when mouse enters it and rotate it back to the original position when mouse leaves. It works ok when I interact with only one div, but when I try hovering over other divs, it starts glitching.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('block-item');

for (var i = 0, max = blocks.length; i < max; i ++) {
    blocks[i].onmouseenter = blocks[i].onmouseleave = handler;
}

var startRotate = function(blackFrame, blackFrameAngle) {
// ...
};

var startRotateBack = function(blackFrame, blackFrameAngle) {
// ...
};

function handler(event) {

  // If mouse enters start rotating clock-wise
  if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {

        // Calculate angles
        var blackFrame = event.target.querySelectorAll('.block-frame')[0];
        var blackFramePos =         getComputedStyle(blackFrame).getPropertyValue('transform');
        var blackFrameValues = blackFramePos.split('(')[1],
        blackFrameValues = blackFrameValues.split(')')[0],
        blackFrameValues = blackFrameValues.split(',');
        var a = blackFrameValues[0];
        var b = blackFrameValues[1];
        var radians = Math.atan2(b, a);
        if ( radians < 0 ) {
            radians += (2 * Math.PI);
        }
        var blackFrameAngle = Math.round( radians * (180/Math.PI));

    // Start rotating
    startRotate(blackFrame, blackFrameAngle);

  }

  // If mouse leaves stop rotating clock-wise and start rotating back
  if (event.type == 'mouseleave') {

  clearInterval(RotateFrame)
  // ...
  // ...
  // Start rotating back
  startRotateBack(blackFrame, blackFrameAngle);

  }

}

});
```

Full code is in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fw3ma9ej/2/

Comment: Why not just use CSS transitions and `:hover`? That wouldn't need any JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, thats an option, but I thought making it with javascript.

Comment: Why would you prefer to use JS over CSS? CSS will be more performant, non-blocking, and much shorter.

Comment: I am currently learning JS, was interested in calculating angles and rotating divs 'manually'.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve it just by using the CSS transition property and change the rotate angle of the element on hover.

you can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/j10y98w2/1/

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
transition: transform 5s ease-out;
&:hover {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}
```